# React Native WebView source.html with section link

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

For a simple react native webview using the `source.html`for content:

```
import * as React from 'react'

const contents =`
    <h1 id="1">Section 1</h1>        
    <h1 id="2">Section 2</h1>
`;

class AboutView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <WebView  source={{ html: contents, baseUrl: '' }} />
    }
}
```

Is there a way to navigate the webview to a specific section using the named anchor, such as `#1` or `#2` like you would put in a url? I know this can be achieved with JS, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution

Comment: Have you tried adding `#2` in `baseUrl` prop ?